# How to tell CMake that install directory depends on phony target?

Tags: dependencies, installation, cmake, target

How do I achieve the following in CMake (using version 2.8.5)? I have documentation generated by a custom target named `doc`, the output of which I would like to include when installing or CPack'ing.

```
add_custom_target( doc "${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE}" Doxyfile )
install( DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/doc DESTINATION doc )
```

The `Doxyfile` tells Doxygen to put out the documentation at `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/doc`.

If I do this in the build directory:

```
make doc
cpack
```

things works fine, because the first line creates the directory on which the `install` target depends.

However, if I have a fresh build (so `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/doc` does not exist yet), and I invoke CPack directly:

```
cpack
```

then it complains that it cannot find `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/doc`:

```
CMake Error at <snip>/build/cmake_install.cmake:36 (FILE):
  file INSTALL cannot find "<snip>/build/doc".
```

I have also tried the following:

```
add_custom_command( OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/doc COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile )
install( DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/doc DESTINATION doc )
```

but I still get the same CPack error, and doing `make doc` in the build directory does not work either.

So if I do the `make doc` manually before `cpack` it works with the configuration at the top of this post, but how can I tell cmake/cpack that the `install` directive depends on the custom target `doc`, so that building the documentation happens automatically when calling `cpack` or `make install`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need `ALL` keyword:

```
add_custom_target( doc ALL "${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE}" Doxyfile )
```

---

**Update:**

Currently cmake does not provide an option to add custom dependencies to its built-in targets (such as `all`, `install`, `test`, etc). And it seems that it will not provide this option in near future - see http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=8438

However it is still possible to achieve desired behavior with some hacks/workarounds. For example you can directly run make tool at the beginning of install step.

So **use on your own risk**:

```
add_custom_target(hack ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Hacking install target")
if("${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" MATCHES Make)
    install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL} hack WORKING_DIRECTORY \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}\")")
endif()
```

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed a possible solution. However, the `ALL` keyword always causes the target to be built. In this case this is not a problem, but I would still be interested in a generic solution where I can add an explicit dependency between the install target (which implicitly depends on `ALL`) and my custom target.

Comment: @ysnikraz I've updated my answer. Unfortunately cmake has no clear way to set dependencies between custom and built-in targets.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your update and the workaround! Just tested it and it works well. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I have changed this a bit in my CMakeList.txt in order to build on both Linux and Windows

```
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL} hack WORKING_DIRECTORY \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}\")") endif()
```

This is my solution. It doesn't build the documentation always "ALL" only when doc or install target are required (On Visual Studio, whe INSTALL project is compiled).
This solution is not complete. It will not work with MinGW, for instance, but...

```
set( DOXYFILE_OUTPUT_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doc )
#-- Configure the Template Doxyfile
configure_file(Doxyfile.in ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile  @ONLY IMMEDIATE)

#-- Add a custom target to run Doxygen
add_custom_target (doc
    COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile
    SOURCES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

if(WIN32)
    install(
        CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL} /Build Debug ABIHex.sln /project doc.vcproj
                              WORKING_DIRECTORY \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}\")"
    )
else(WIN32)
    install(
        CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL} --build --target doc
                              WORKING_DIRECTORY \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}\")"
    )
endif(WIN32)
```

Hope it will be useful for someone.

Regards,
Alex